# What is wrong with my heroku asset:compilation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am trying to insert an image into a mailer, everything runs locally but heroku doesn't see the image on its server despite pushing and precompiling as I'm ought to do. Code as below;

*user_mailer.rb*

```
def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    attachments.inline['my_logo_sml.png'] = File.read('app/assets/images/my_logo_sml.png')
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to Mybiz')
end
```

*welcome_email.html.erb*

```
<td class="six sub-columns header_logo">
    <%= image_tag attachments["my_logo_sml.png"].url -%>
</td>
```

*gemfile*

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

`app/assets/images/my_logo_sml.png` is clearly present and getting through the pipline locally.

I have run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` a number of times, I have `heroku restart`'ed a number of times.

Heroku logs:

```
2015-06-03T22:38:50.824191+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - app/assets/images/my_logo_sml.png)
```

I'm at a loss after hours going round and around on this, can anyone help me please?

**Update**

After hours of looking at this i feel like it's not a syntax issue but an asset pre-compilation issue of some sort, I've copied my config/environments/production.rb code below if anyone can spot anything wrong?:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true #concerned that this is the right thing to do?
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://mysite.co'
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

Perhaps I could clean all compiled assets out and start the whole thing again, could anyone advise as to how to do this?

**Update**

The source of my problem seemed to be confusion between local and slug asset compilation. I ran `heroku run rake assets:clobber` and this solved all of my problems. Full understanding of what precisely was going on still eludes me, however running the above and having `config.assets.compile = true` in config/environments/production.rb has everything working just fine and upon `git push heroku` it shows me clearly that it's running both `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:precompile` just fine. Syntax used in the view was:

*welcome_email.html.erb*

```
<%= image_tag('my_logo_sml.png', alt: "My Logo Small")%>
```

I'm still unsure as to whether having `config.assets.compile = true` is the correct thing to do despite it seeming to solve the problem, i wonder whether it might end up compiling assets on multiple occasions?

Comment: Try to run it in rails console `file_name = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'my_long_sml.png') File.read(file_name)`

Comment: Have you run the above two commands.? And is it giving you the result or any error you are getting

Comment: And you want to send it as an attachment or you want to display in welcome email template

Comment: Try this `<%= image_tag("my_logo_sml.png")%>` in your email template

Comment: the file system is case sensitive, double check this.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file from Rails console as suggested by @user123 shows that the paths are correct and the file is there. Trying to reading the file from Heroku run console does not find the file and comes up with the same `Errno::ENOENT no such file error` Strangely heroku is serving an image in the homepage which i try to load as described above in heroku console and it is unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I think welcome_email.html.erb file can not be .erb file. There is a workaround. You can put image somewhere on the web like Amazon or Image share services and use link as source.

```
<img src='https://example.com'>
```

Comment: There's a fair bit of erb in there so really I need it to be an erb file. There should be no problem with this should there. After hours of looking at this I feel like the issue lies in asset compilation issues. I've added my config/environments/production.rb code above if that gives anyone any further ideas?